# PyQt5 QWidget Stopping running application when opening QWidget as separate window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 Application and I have created a reproducible example but will explain first. I have the `MainWindow` class which is a `QStackedWidget` and I have a Custom `QWidget` class called CustomPopup. When I call this class with a QTableWidget I can open the popup as long as I don't use the following line:

```
header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
#or
header.setSectionResizeMode(0,QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

This line is what stops the window from opening and it will open it if I remove it. Here is the reproducible code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *   
import sys
class MainWindow(QStackedWidget):
        class CustomRemovePopup(QWidget):
            def __init__(self,parent:'MainWindow',e=None) -> None:
                super().__init__()
                self.p=parent
                self.setWindowTitle("Remove A Card From Study Set")
                self.setGeometry(200,200,400,400)
                self.layou=QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
                self.layou.setObjectName("Remove Cards From Study Set")
                self.setLayout(self.layou)
                #add a keypress event to press the enter button
                self.keyPressEvent=QShortcut("Return",self)
                self.table=QTableWidget()
                self.table.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
                #"font: 20pt Comic Sans MS; color: white;"
                self.table.setColumnWidth(0,300)
                self.table.selectColumn(1)
                header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
                header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
                header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
                self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Term","Definition"])
                self.layou.addWidget(self.table)
        def showCustomPopup(self,e=None):
            self.customPopup=self.CustomRemovePopup(parent=self)
            self.customPopup.show()
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__() 
            self.setWindowTitle("Testing")
            self.wid=QWidget()
            self.layout=QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
            self.wid.setLayout(self.layout)
            self.btn=QPushButton("Click Me")
            self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showCustomPopup)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
            self.addWidget(self.wid)
            self.setCurrentWidget(self.wid)
if __name__ =="__main__":
       app = QApplication(sys.argv)
       window = MainWindow()
       window.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `self.table.setColumnCount(2)`.

Comment: `QTableWidget` doesn't automatically set the column count based on setting HorizontalHeaderLabels?

Comment: If I recall correctly, no. In any case, you could test it yourself by moving that line *before* `setSectionResizeMode()`, which is the main culprit: you can only call it with indexes that refer to existing sections.

Comment: Also why doesn't this raise an Error for Invalid amount of Columns

Comment: Nor PyQt or PySide raise Qt errors, and this is caused by Qt (I don't remember the reason right now, but there should be a couple of similar posts on the matter here on SO).

Comment: I did get it down to the `setSectionResizeMode()` but originally thought it was the way I defined `QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContent` as I originally was using `QHeaderView.ResizeToContent` which was shown to be undefined in IDE and I found `ResizeMode` to be a subclass of `QHeaderView`

Comment: That syntax has become available in recent PyQt5 versions (but the old convention is still valid) and is mandatory only since PyQt6. In *that* case you'd have got a Python exception, but an AttributeError one, because the old naming isn't available in the class namespace anymore. Note that `ResizeMode` is not a subclass, it's a class member, specifically an Enum.